# How to generate JSON Stringer in Android for this format

Tags: java, android, json

I need to send data to database in this format -

```
{"param1":"value1", "param2":"value2", "param3": {"username": "admin", "password": "123"}}
```

How to generate this using JSONStringer ?

I tried this -

```
vm = new JSONStringer().object().key("param1").value("value1")
                  .object().key("param2").value("value2")
                    .key("param3").object()
                    .key("username").value("admin")
                    .key("password").value("123")
                    .endObject().endObject().endObject();
```

But I'm getting this error -

> org.json.JSONException: Nesting problem at
>   org.json.JSONStringer.beforeValue(JSONStringer.java:415)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject();

object1.put("param1", "value1");
object1.put("param2", "param2");

JSONObject innerObject1 = new JSONObject();
innerObject1.put("username", "admin");
innerObject1.put("password", "123");

object1.put("param3",innerObject1);

String jsonStr = object1.toString();
```

Ideally reverse of JSON parsing can be applied to create a json string object, so that the same can be send to Server/DB

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  try {
        JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
        object.put("param1","value1");
        object.put("param2","value2");
        JSONObject param3=new JSONObject();
        paraam3.put("username","admin");
        paraam3.put("password","123");
        object.put("param3",param3);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Exception handling shouldn't really be part of the answer as it is not relevant

Answer (score 1):

You can create model which will be your java file same as your JSON file and can use **[`gson`](https://github.com/google/gson)** library which is supported by Google to do JSON parsing. The library is quite flexible and easy to use then using traditional method of JSON parsing.

Model File

```
public class Response {
public String param1;
public String param2;
public Param3 param3;
public Response(String param1, String param2) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
}
      public class Param3 {
            public String username;
            public String password;

    public Param3(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
      }
}
```

In file in which you insert data

```
Response res = new Response("value1", "value2", new Param3("admin","123"));
String dbResult = new Gson.toJson(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the actual solution using org.json.JSONStringer

```
JSONWriter writer = stringer3.object()
            .key("param1").value("value1")
            .key("param2").value("value2")
            .key("param3").object()
                .key("username").value("admin")
                .key("password").value("123")
            .endObject()
            .endObject();
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

You can think of the **object()** method as opening a new parenthesis and the **endObject()** as closing it