# How to send a POST request with JSON body using Volley?

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

How to pass these parameter into POST method using Volley library.

API link: http://api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/searches?api_key=12345&ts_code=123

[Screenshot of JSON structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbkZd.png)

I tried this but again facing error.

```
StringEntity params= new StringEntity ("{\"trip\":\"[\"{\"departure_code\":\","
                     +departure,"arrival_code\":\"+"+arrival+","+"outbound_date\":\","
                     +outbound,"inbound_date\":\","+inbound+"}\"]\"}");
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
```

Please visit [here](https://support.wan.travel/hc/en-us/articles/200191669-Wego-Flights-API) for the details of API.

Comment: quick tip: switch to Okhttp or retrofit, volley is slower and would be hard from a beginner's perspective, while okhttp would be easier for you!

Comment: What you need to do is to pass the json as body in the post request using okhttp, let me know if this helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179922/okhttp-post-body-as-json

Comment: If you insist on using Volley itself, you can refer this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley

Comment: @superman thanks . I'll try

Comment: Solved the problem?

Comment: @superman no :(

Comment: try {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://api.wego.com/flights/api/k/2/searches?api_key=123&ts_code=123");
            StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"trip\":\"[\"{\"departure_code\":\",",departure,"arrival_code\":\",",arrival,"outbound_date\":\",",outbound,"inbound_date\":\",",inbound,"}\"""]");
            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
}

Comment: what's your email?

Comment: email-id monikaarora1990@gmail.com

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Usual way is to use a `HashMap` with Key-value pair as request parameters with Volley

Similar to the below example, you need to customize for your specific requirement.

**Option 1:**

```
final String URL = "URL";
// Post params to be sent to the server
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("token", "token_value");
params.put("login_id", "login_id_value");
params.put("UN", "username");
params.put("PW", "password");

JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
       new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
               try {
                   //Process os success response
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
           }
       });

// add the request object to the queue to be executed
ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request_json);
```

> NOTE: A HashMap can have custom objects as value

**Option 2:**

Directly using JSON in request body

```
try {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String URL = "http://...";
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    jsonBody.put("firstkey", "firstvalue");
    jsonBody.put("secondkey", "secondobject");
    final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("LOG_VOLLEY", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String responseString = "";
            if (response != null) {

                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

            }
            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i just post these parameter in post method

Comment: {
  "trips": [
    {
      "departure_code": "SYD",
      "arrival_code": "LON",
      "outbound_date": "2014-01-24",
      "inbound_date": "2014-01-29"
    }
  ],
  "adults_count": 1,
  "locale": "ar"
}

Comment: @ Stallion yes i pass these parameter in post method ...check link its flight api

Comment: @ Stallion ur code work for me but little bit issue facing please help me

Comment: What's the issue you are facing ?  I guess if its the problem with JSON forming , then this solution will help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894424/how-to-generate-json-stringer-in-android-for-this-format/37894478#37894478

Comment: @ Stallion yes  output :{"adults_count":"1","inbound_date":"2014-01-29","arrival_code":"LON","departure_code":"SYD","outbound_date":"2014-01-24"}
 but i want this output :- {
  "trips": [
    {
      "departure_code": "SYD",
      "arrival_code": "LON",
      "outbound_date": "2014-01-24",
      "inbound_date": "2014-01-29"
    }
  ],
  "adults_count": 1
}

Comment: @ Stallion Thanks alot  Today you saved my life :) thank you so much

Comment: i got response status 200 not full response ..u can help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by not full response ?

Comment: thanks for reply .. now i got full response in json format

Comment: but can anyone tell me how can i  see or debug API response in Logcat?  i put Log.d("response",response.toString()) but not getting anything ... but Toast being shown with a response.

Answer (score -1):

this is an example uses `StringRequest`

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Method.POST, url,  listener, errorListener) {  
    @Override  
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {  
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
        map.put("api_key", "12345");  
        map.put("ts_code", "12345");  
        return map;  
    }  
};
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? The body of the POST request is json.

Comment: @Ricky.Lee  i am not asking  api_key and ts_code .api_key and ts_code  add url link its working fine.. i am asking about json data like trip [ {}]

Answer (score -3):

```
 OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();   
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(parameter1Name, parameter1Value);
            values.put(parameter2Name, parameter2Value);

            RequestBody requestBody = null;

            if (values != null && values.size() > 0) {
                FormEncodingBuilder formEncoding = new FormEncodingBuilder();

                Set<String> keySet = values.keySet();
                for (String key : keySet) {
                    try {
                        values.getAsString(key);
                        formEncoding.add(key, values.getAsString(key));

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.log(Logger.LEVEL_ERROR, CLASS_NAME, "getRequestBodyFromParameters", "Error while adding Post parameter. Skipping this parameter." + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
                requestBody = formEncoding.build();
            }

            String URL = "http://example.com";
            Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
            builder.url(URL);
            builder.post(requestBody);
            Request request = builder.build();
            Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: i just post these value {
  "trips": [
    {
      "departure_code": "SYD",
      "arrival_code": "LON",
      "outbound_date": "2014-01-24",
      "inbound_date": "2014-01-29"
    }
  ],
  "adults_count": 1,
  "locale": "ar"
}

Comment: @Pawandeep Kaur has asked for volley body post parameters and not Okhttp, where both are completely different libraries in their format