# How to test volley POST?

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I want to test POST request on android. I don't have a web host. There are some android-volley request example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079174/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-json-body-using-volley).

How can I find a free url to allow post the requestes?

Answer (score 0):

There a few i can think of :

- https://httpbin.org/post
- http://requestb.in/
- www.posttestserver.co

I am sure there are more.

These are good for general experiments, however I would use something more customizable and locally installed like https://nodered.org/ and for actual tests something that actually runs on the device with the tests like:

- [MockWebserver](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)
- [RESTMock](https://github.com/andrzejchm/RESTMock)
- [wiremock](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock) - [example](https://github.com/handstandsam/wiremock-android)
- Custom solution mocking the [HttpStack](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpStack.java)(the last point before flushing the data to the wire)